# How to search to search a file for string, display the line containing the string and also the 6 lines preceding it

Tags: c#

I am trying to search through a text file for a string, once I have found this string I need to display this line and then also display the 6 preceding lines i.e. which will contain the details about the error message in the string. I have been searching for similar code and have found the following code but it doesn’t meet my requirements, just wondering if it's possible to do this.

Thanks,
John.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string cacheline = "";
    string line;

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new   
    System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\AccessOutlook.txt");
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         if (line.Contains("errors"))
         {
             lines.Add(cacheline);
         }
         cacheline = line;
         }
         file.Close();

         foreach (var l in lines)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file small enough to hold in memory?

Comment: Is the line you are looking for only in the file once?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it should be small enough to hold in memory I think.

Comment: Thanks Mark, no the "errors" line that I am looking for could be in the file numerous times. Apologies for the delay in replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Queue<string> lines = new Queue<string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(args[0]))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("error"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
                foreach (var errLine in lines)
                    Console.WriteLine(errLine);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
            }

            lines.Enqueue(line);

            while (lines.Count > 6)
                lines.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Keith.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep caching the lines until you find the line you are looking for:

```
using(var file = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\AccessOutlook.txt"))
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!line.Contains(myString))
        {
           lines.Add(line);
        } 
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Concat(new[] { line })));
        }

        if(lines.Count > 6) lines.RemoveAt(0);
     }

}
```

Comment: I would use a Queue instead of List in `List<string> lines = new List<string>();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string filename = "filename"; // Put your own filename here.
string target   = "target"; // Put your target string here.

int numLinesToShow = 7;

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
int index = Array.FindIndex(lines, element => element.Contains(target));

if (index >= 0)
{
    int start = Math.Max(0, index - numLinesToShow + 1);
    var result = lines.Skip(start).Take(numLinesToShow).ToList();

    // Use result.
}
```

Comment: This will only output a single match, and requires the entire file be read into memory, and then searched, and then doing a Skip() which could potentially enumerate all the lines again, and then creating a new list.

Comment: @Keith Using `Skip()` on an array is optimsed to O(1), so that's not an issue. Creating a list with at most 7 elements is not an issue (but if you want you can omit the `ToList()` and it will still give you the set of strings to display). The OP doesn't mention outputting multiple matches.

Comment: Sure, of course Skip is optimized for a list, but I tend to be careful when using it since at least in my experience, someone will come along and refactor the code to not be a list, and suddenly the Skip can get relatively expensive. :) Anyway, not being argumentative, just saying overall it's a fairly 'dirty' answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Matthew.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will open the file, search for the line you want, and then write the 6 preceeding lines to the Console.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
int lineIndex;
for (lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lines.Length - 1; lineIndex++)
{
    if (lines[lineIndex] == textToFind)
    {
        break;
    }
}

var startLine = Math.Max(0, lineIndex - 6);
for (int i = startLine; i < lineIndex; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
}
```